# Post Twitter in_reply_to_status_id from javascript api

Tags: javascript, twitter

The [twitter js api documentation](http://platform.twitter.com/js-api.html) seems very clear on the reply call, yet I cannot get it to work. My tweets are getting posted, but no matter what I attempt the in_reply_to_status_id is not getting appended to the status update. Does anyone have a working example they can share?

Here is what seems to me to be the correct translation of the js api docs:

```
T.Status.update('message', {in_reply_to_status_id: '123456789'}); //where in_reply_to_status_id is part of the options object
```

Or

```
T.Status.reply('message', '123456789'); //where in_reply_to_status_id is the second param passed
```

Comment: Can you show your code, so we can look at it to see what's wrong?

Comment: Sure thing. I went through at least 20 iterations, but I'll post what I think the api docs are trying to get across.

Comment: What does `T.Status.update` return?

Comment: Both update and reply return a status object, but in all cases the inReplyToStatusID is empty, and checking the actual Twitter stream confirms this.

Comment: I was finding that with this code `T.Status.reply('message', '123456789');` the id was being posted as the text of the status so it seems like the id should be first followed by the message, like `T.Status.reply('123456789', 'message');`, but the in_reply_to_status_id field remains empty even then.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, as the API docs you linked to aren't a good example of nice documentation, but I suspect the `in_reply_to_status_id` has to be a number, not a string. Can you try it with

```
T.Status.reply('message', 123456789);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make a difference (I checked). I'm using strings in all other Twitter calls, and they handle that fine, especially with the new changes to their id structure: http://dev.twitter.com/announcements